# Objective-C / Cocoa equivalent of C# ManualResetEvent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, multithreading

Is there an equivalent of the .NET ManualResetEvent class available for use in Objective-C / Cocoa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with ManualResetEvent, but [based on the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx), it looks like [the NSCondition class](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html) might be what you are looking for.

NSCondition is by no means an exact equivalent, but it does provide similar signaling functionality. You might also want to read up on [NSLock](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Reading up on the doc's this appears to do exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: It looks like NSCondition is more like AutoResetEvent and not ManualResetEvent.

Comment: Check out this useful sample:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158397/equivalent-of-gcd-serial-dispatch-queue-in-ios-3-x/6258379#6258379

Answer (score 2):

Here is a wrapper class I created which emulates ManualResetEvent using [NSCondition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW18).

```
@interface WaitEvent : NSObject {
    NSCondition *_condition;
    bool _signaled;
}

- (id)initSignaled:(BOOL)signaled;
- (void)waitForSignal;
- (void)signal;

@end

@implementation WaitEvent

- (id)initSignaled:(BOOL)signaled
{
    if (self = ([super init])) {
        _condition = [[NSCondition alloc] init];
        _signaled = signaled;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)waitForSignal
{
    [_condition lock];
    while (!_signaled) {
        [_condition wait];
    }

    [_condition unlock];
}

- (void)signal
{
    [_condition lock];
    _signaled = YES;
    [_condition signal];
    [_condition unlock];
}

@end
```

I've done just some basic testing but I think it should get the job done with much less ceremony.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the sample code I would have liked to find yesterday (but couldn't find anywhere). If you want to create a producer/consumer class where the consumer is asynchronous, this is what you need to do :

You need to declare and allocate the NSConditionLock.

```
NSArray * data = [self getSomeData];

if ( [data count] == 0 ) {
  NSLog(@"sendThread: Waiting...");
  [_conditionLock lockWhenCondition:1];
  [_conditionLock unlockWithCondition:0];
  NSLog(@"sendThread: Back to life...");
}
else {
  // Processing
}
```

And in the main code, when you add data and you want to unlock the other thread, you just have to add :

```
[_conditionLock lock];
[_conditionLock unlockWithCondition:1];
```

Note: I don't describe here how data are exchanged between the producer and the consumer. In my program it was going through an SQLite/CoreData database, so thread sync is done at a higher level. But if you use a NSMutableDictionary, you need to add some NSLock.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, those are poor man's condition variables.

You could use the `NSCondition` class, but I think it's better
to go straight to the source. Start with `pthread_cond_init`.

You gonna love it.

Comment: NSCondition is a higher-level wrapper around pthreads. If the NSCondition/NSLock interface does the job, there's no need to go low-level.

Comment: Well I guess you _could_ do it the easy way.