# How to wait for an event or timeout

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying a simple thread program.
I need to wait for a event and time delay. This time delay is varying. How to do this?

Can anyone explain with a sample program? I know how to spawn a thread with `NSThreads` as well as through `NSInvocationOperation`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Threading in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251202/threading-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait for a timeout consider using [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html). You can use `setFireDate` method to modify time delay. 
For asynchronous events there's a lot of way to solve the problem, according to what you need in your program: first of all you may simply setting a delegate that receive a message when something happen in your class. If you need something more complex (in order to avoid race conditions or deadlocks) you may consider use [NSNotificationCenter](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=WcHsTfiiBdCp-gbczenWDw&usg=AFQjCNGQFG_x--jlHIVx43FTud119GEblw&sig2=N828tw6AELsyjXtvuY1olQ) or [NSConnection](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=k8HsTfPOF4Ps-gaJ27WjAQ&usg=AFQjCNEwbtiTwWslchrpvGgjQs4YBRqghQ&sig2=BG65Ma4Q2sNJxfVDkPdeEw).